# Microsoft Security Essentials flagging Google Chrome as malware

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, google-chrome, malware, ms-security-essentials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome detected as PWS:Win32/Zbot by MSE](https://superuser.com/questions/341656/google-chrome-detected-as-pwswin32-zbot-by-mse)

Since friday, Microsoft Security Essentials began falsely identifying Google Chrome as a piece of malware ("PWS:Win32/Zbot")

I am unable to launch Chrome or load new web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for only posting the link, but it's got detailed instructions how to clean up the mess.
http://chrome.blogspot.com/2011/09/problems-with-microsoft-security.html

(If needed, I'll edit my answer to contain all the information that can be found in the blog post.)

Comment: Thanks... I only vote-up complete full answers (in addition to the link, add its contents.).

Comment: If at all, you should probably post the complete answer at the duplicate anyway, would be better (less fragmentation).